# Finding the norm of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

When finding the norm of the vector:

> Find $\|2w-2y\|$ such that $w=(1/2,3,1)$ and $y=(0,-1,3/2)$.

answer:

$$\begin{align*}
&2(1/2,3,1)= (1,6,2)\\
&2(0,-1,3/2) =(0,-2,3)\\
&(1,6,2)- (0,-2,3) = (1,8,-1)\\
&\sqrt{ 1^2 +8^2+(-1)^2}=\sqrt{66}= 8.124
\end{align*}$$

Is this the correct way of doing it?

Thanks

Comment: It is indeed; my only criticism is that $\sqrt{66}$ isn’t **equal** to $8.124$, but only **approximately** equal.

Comment: Okay, i'll bear that in mind, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's correct, you can also do the subtraction first:

$\|2w-2y\|= \|2(w-y)\|= 2(1/2,4,-1/2)=(1,8,-1)$